Primitive idempotent and bilateral ideals
I'm trying to show for my algebra class that in a semisimple ring with unity $R$ (not necessarily commutative), every primitive idempotent element must belong to a minimal two-sided ideal.
Here, by saying that $e\in R$ is primitive idempotent we mean that it is idempotent (i.e. $e^2=e$), and it cannot be expressed as sum of the form $e=i+j$ with $i,j$ non-trivial idempotents s.t. $ij=0$.
I showed that in such an $R$ there are at most finitely many two-sided minimal ideals $I_1,\ldots,I_n$ and it admits the decomposition $R=K\oplus \bigoplus_{j\leq n} I_j$ for some left ideal $K$ of $R$.
Moreover, I know that a left ideal $J$ of $R$ is minimal iff there is a primitive idempotent $e$ s.t. $J=Re$. However, any similar argument that I try does not seem to work in this case.
Also, I found no evidence of this property in the literature. Is it true?
If anyone has a hint or a reference to suggest I would appreciate it.

A semisimple ring has to have a finite lattice of ideals.
